# Using Multi Matrix Variables in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem that I cannot solve. I try to figure out the matrix variables in Spring MVC. Matrix variable has been enabled. Here is my project structure:

[image: projectStructure]

I inspect a handler function in *ProductController* :

```
// added in page 102
@RequestMapping("/products/filter/{params}/{specification}")
public String filter(@MatrixVariable(pathVar = "params") Map<String, List<String>> criteriaFilter,
        @MatrixVariable(pathVar = " specification") Map<String, List<String>> specFilter, Model model) {

    System.out.println("inside filter function.");
    
    return "products";
}
```

when I call the url:

> http://localhost:8080/springmvc197/products/filter/params;brands=Google,Dell;categories=Tablet,Laptop/specification;dimension=10,20,15;color=red,green,blue

*criteriaFilter* is filled with categories and brand variable, as it was supposed to, but *specification* is not filled. What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you try without space , i.e -  `"specification"` ?

Comment: what a lack of attention. I haven't noticed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As R.G pointed out, when I try it without space, it works.